# Ember unable to access dynamic segment parameter

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have my Router.js defined as below;

```
this.route('step1', function() {
      this.route('step2dynamic', {path: '/:dynamic_step_name'}, function(){
            this.route('step3a');            
            this.route('step3b');
      });
});
```

Now in one of my routes, I do

```
this.transitionTo('step1.step2dynamic.step3a', 'step2DynamicValue');
```

In my routes\step1\step2dynamic\step3a.js, I have the model hook defined as

```
model: function(params) {
    // Why is params not contain the passed parameter value ?
}
```

Here I am not getting the params.dynamic_step_name. It is an empty object.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just an update..I also tried
this.transitionTo('step1.step2dynamic.step3a', {dynamic_step_name: 'step2DynamicValue' });

Still does not work

Comment: This is most likely happening because your model hook with params should live higher up, on the route with params. Model is passed down but params aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only be in the params of the model hook belonging to the route containing the dynamic segment.

You shouldn't need the param in your step 3 route because your step 2 route should handle any fetching of model data using the dynamic segment. But, if for some reason you need to reference it in the step 3 route, it would be accessible to you in the `transition` passed into `beforeModel` and `model`:

```
// routes/step1/step2dynamic/step3a.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model (params, transition) {
    // should log { dynamic_step_name: "step2DynamicValue" }
    console.log(transition.params["step1.step2dynamic"]);
  }
});
```

Again though, if you're using it to fetch data, it should be handled in the step 2 route.